How to generate FCM token with PL/SQL
I have Firebase integrated with Oracle APEX so I am able to send notifictions token generated manually for testing.
I want to generate the token with PL/SQL not sure it is possible since there are a lot dependecies.
Examples - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const key = require('../placeholders/service-account.json');
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
}


use apex_web_service.make_rest_request API to make a post request.

@KoenLostrie Yes, but how to set jwtClient variable as in Node.js code above.

No idea - that javascript code wasn't in the question when posted my comment...

Yes, I edited it, sorry. Just found this one - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/24.1/aeapi/APEX_JWT.html#GUID-D44A3F15-75BE-41DC-A557-17FA70D466B9

will check if that can help
